# Как присвоить строке новое значение в C++?

Tags: c++

Пробую присвоить строке символов новое значение:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    char string[]="qazqazqaz";
    string[]="zaqzaqzaq";
}
```

В строке `string[]="zaqzaqzaq";` ошибка, красным выделены квадратные скобки, курсор между ними и ошибка: [Error] expected primary-expression before ']' token

Как правильно присвоить строке символов новое значение?

Comment: `int main()`, а не просто `main()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы пишете на C++, то зачем вам **char**? Используйте готовый объект типа **string**:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    string line = "qazqazqaz";
    line = "zaqzaqzaq";
}
```

Можете почитать [здесь](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/).

Comment: Очень неудачное имя для переменной вы выбрали.

Comment: C++ НЕ поддерживает `int` по-умолчанию

Comment: @GreenDragon: Как впрочем и С его уже давно не поддерживает.

Comment: @zed , да, пожалуй для начинающих это не очень удачное название переменной. Спасибо за указание! ;)

Answer (score 1):

насколько я понел речь шла о инициализации массива, а не как получать строку

```
char string[] = "qazqazqaz";
char s[] = "zaqzaqzaq";
strcpy(string, s);
cout << string;
```

Comment: А если новая строка будет длиннее?

Comment: @zed  это уже другой вопрос

Comment: Поскольку вы рассмотрели лишь крайний случай, когда обе строки имеют одинаковый размер, ваш ответ по сути бесполезен. Вопрос же в том, как динамически присваивать строке другое значение, которое может и не совпадать по длине.

Comment: @ zed,  я читать умею,  но не нашел в вопросе  даже намека  на ваше утверждение.  Просто простой ответ на простой вопрос - не вижу надобности  обсуждать дальше.  Даже неинтересно... То что у вас есть знания по С строкам, я уже понел

Comment: Самая последняя строка в вопросе: *Как правильно присвоить строке символов новое значение?* И раз там не сказано, что надо присвоить строку того же самого размера, то стоит воспринимать вопрос в общем.

Comment: @ zed, вот так и нужно - вместо того, чтоб обсуждать "какого размера у тети...", поставили просто минус. Вот так нужно всегда...  Но я дам вам один совет:  не пытайтесь  рассказывать ребенку о таблице умножения, если он у вас спрашивает сколько будет дважды два...